# Turn off tracked changes in Outlook 2013 while in Draft mode

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

How do I turn off the grey (sometimes red) bar while editing my email in Draft mode?

[image]

Clicking it does not do anything. This recent [thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_winother/turn-off-track-changes-in-outlook-draft-mode/c25d7eec-51ad-4ec2-b685-75943d059049) failed to have a solution.

Comment: What's your Outlook version?

Comment: @thims Outlook 2013, edited the subject for more informative title.